# Issue in removing time stamp in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, timestamp

I want to convert 12/8/2006 12:30:00 to 12/8/2006

I tried -

```
1. trunc(TO_DATE (effective_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS'))
2. TO_DATE (effective_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

But all these are returning values as 12/8/0006.

Why Oracle is returning year 0006 instead of 200[image]6.

Comment: What is the data type of `effective_date_time`?

Comment: I can't observe that behavior: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e837b/1 Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Date type of effective_date_time is date only, I have added the screen shot

Comment: You're not converting a date with a time to just a date - because DATE also includes the time - always. Even when you don't see it. Your function call is telling the database to format the value such that you don't see the time piece.

If you don't want the 12:30:00, you can update the value to be 12/8/2006 00:00:00 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
trunc(effective_date_time)
```

It's a date, you don't need TO_DATE

When you're using TO_DATE(effective_date_time, 'format') on a DATE column, effective_date_time is converted to a char using NLS params. I suppose your NLS settings is something like 'dd/mm/yy'. That's why you get a wrong year.

A simple example:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yy';
select trunc(TO_DATE (sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS')) from dual;

November, 22 0014 00:00:00+0000


alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
select trunc(TO_DATE (sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS')) from dual;

November, 22 2014 00:00:00+0000
```

Answer (score 2):

If `effective_date_time` is a `date` column using `to_date()` is totally useless.

It will first (implicitely!) convert the `date` to a `varchar` (based on the NLS settings, just to convert it back to a `date` again.

If you want a specific format for your date column use `to_char()`

```
to_char(effective_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:Mi:SS')
```

**Never use `to_date()` on `date` or `timestamp` columns!**

Answer (score 1):

Your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` has year as '`YY`' in year.. And then you specify the format at `YYYY` again in to_date, so `2006`, first interpretted as `06` again ended up as `0006`.

Sincere advice, dont do `To_DATE()` on a date. Just `TRUNC(yourdate)` is what you need.

Comment: can I change NLS_DATE_Format?

Comment: Yes.. ALTER SESSION is what you need.. but it is session specific. When you run your query ina different environment. It is not guranteed to return same result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

trunc(effective_date_time)
Trunc will directly remove the time stamp from the date format